# mod_rewrite not working xampp (with picture)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I've look through the tutorials in web, and below is what I had done to test if mod_rewrite work.

First: Uncomment the mod_rewrite.so(@httpd.conf)

Second: Allowoverride -> Allowoverride all(@httpd.conf)

Third:(@.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^dra/?$    draft.php  [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

finally: if my code work the url should be rewritten to `localhost/xampp/test/dra/` according to (editted from) [url-rewriting for beginner](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

[image: mod rewrite not working]

Final result: mod_rewrite not working, as you can see in the picture. Anything that I had left out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
RewriteRule ^xampp/test/dra/?$ /xampp/test/draft.php [NC,L]
```

Or simply:

```
RewriteRule dra/?$ /xampp/test/draft.php  [NC,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` takes from what comes after `domain/` in your case it would what comes after `http://127.0.0.1/` or `http://localhost/`.

Also this rule is not to change your draft.php, this rule you have is to allow you to access:

```
http://localhost/xampp/test/dra/
```

And have your draft.php serve it without showing it.

Comment: Object not found! when using `http://localhost/xampp/test/dra/` and `RewriteRule  dra/?$    draft.php  [NC,L]`, futhermore apache restarted

Comment: @Anonymous yes excuse me, you need to add the path to the file, have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In **httpd-xammp.conf**

transform

**`Allowoverride AuthConfig`** to **`Allowoverride All`**

I think it will help you

Comment: You can also add this directive to apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I was following [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708), and the problem for me was the suggested line:

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteRule .* good.html
```

did not work. It has to be on two separate lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* good.html
```